# How to Find Last Change row in SQL - Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can someone please provide a query that I can use in Google Big Query to identify the total count of users for whom the value changed specifically from 'C' to 'P'? In the below table userid=123 satisfies this even though later userid = 123 changes back from 'P' to 'C'.

```
userid    timestamp            Value
123       9-15-2020 02:35:45   C
456       9-15-2020 01:45:09   P
789       9-15-2020 06:22:10   P
123       9-15-2020 03:43:00   P
456       9-15-2020 03:45:10   C
123       9-15-2020 07:40:34   C
```

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS

Comment: SELECT maximal `timestamp` per `userid` in subquery, select the whole row by these values in main query from another table copy, test `value` for `'C'` value.

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: @akina - Can you please provide the SQL query?

Comment: @Fahmi - The desired output is to run a loop to identify value change from 'P' to 'C so I can get the total count of users who are changing the status.

Comment: add the desired output in table format as you've added the sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please provide a query that I can use in Google Big Query to identify the total count of users for whom the value changed specifically from 'C' to 'P'

Note that this is not consistent with the title of the question.

`lag()` is the key idea.  But it is unclear whether you want the count of users or the count of changes.  This calculates both:

```
select count(*) as num_changes,
       count(distinct userid) as num_users_with_change
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over(partition by userid order by timestamp) as prev_value
      from tablename t
     ) t
where value = 'P' and prev_value = 'C';
```

The second column counts a user only once, regardless of the number of times they have changed (which is my interpretation of your question).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `lag()`

```
select userid from
(
select userid, timestamp, value, lag(value) over(partition by userid order by timestamp) as prev_value
from tablename
)A where value='P' and prev_value='C'
```

Answer (score 0):

> identify the total count of users for whom the value changed specifically from 'C' to 'P'?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS qualified_users
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY userid
HAVING STRPOS(STRING_AGG(value, '' ORDER BY timestamp), 'CP') > 0
```

Note; I assume your timestamp column is of TIMESTAMP data type - otherwise you will need to use [PARSE_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) in ORDER BY portion

Comment: thank you. the lag option worked but I will try this too!

Comment: Sure. try and compare how verbose are lag based solutions vs, simplicity of this one! but obviously lag option is a classic way. but I am usually not going classic way as I am trying to show different tricky options and power of BigQuery - see my other answers. in any case  - consider voting up if the answer was helpful   :o)